# problem referencing file in PHP

Tags: php, path

I'm having some problems referencing a file on my website in a PHP script. Let's say the full path is

```
www.mydomain.com/img/peggy.jpg
```

I can't use relative addressing like in

```
../img/peggy.jpg
```

because the script is in an include file which is included in several files at different levels.

```
/img/peggy.jpg
```

doesn't seem to work either. How do I reference to an absolute path?
TIA
Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by writing the full path explicitly:

```
/home2/mydomain/public_html/img/peggy.jpg
```

Note to self: will have to edit this if I ever move to another hosting service. Even my current hosting service (Bluehost) may one day decide to rearrange its file structure.
Other solutions are still welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You could `define(BASE_PATH, dirname(__FILE__))` in your index.php.
Then use `$fileName = BASE_PATH . "/img/peggy.jpg";`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use `dirname(__FILE__) . "/img/peggy.jpg"`.

You can use multiple, as well: `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` ...

Comment: This (the 2nd form) gives the full path as in `http://mydomain.com/img/peggy.jpg`, but it doesn't seem to be in the form expected by `file_exists`; it reports that the file doesn't exist, while it does. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: file_exists takes a relative path, not in the form of a URL. Using `file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . "/img/peggy.jpg")` will return TRUE if the file exists and is not inaccessible.

Comment: For example, http://skydrive.provanix.com/ (one of my subdomains), shows the path of the page index.php (the page that you see). The last line shows that index.php exists. The folder htdocs is my site root, and _skydrive is my subdomain folder.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` points to the absolute path of the current web root.

Comment: Thanks. Seemed to work until I tried a file in a subdomain, like `sub.mydomain.com`. Then I get as full path `/home2/mydomain/public_html/sub/img/peggy.jpg`. The `sub` shouldn't be there. Is there a way to get rid of it?